# Building projects with Maven offline without using M2 repo but using system jars

Tags: linux, maven-2, maven, package-managers

I have a requirement for a project in an open source operating system, to use Maven completely offline under *nix environment. i.e. it should use the dependencies available in the system (probably at /usr/share/* + few other places?). Maven should not download any dependency from internet.

Is there a solution to achieve this? Creating the M2 repo in the system is not a viable solution. The issue is that the file system is read-only. We can only work on a temporary folder (/tmp for example) *with* write access. But maintaining a repo at a temporary location is a bad design, isn't it? 
Saying it another way, the new to be installed maven project should use the existing packages in the system, if available. If packages does not exist, it should get installed separately ( via the package manager), and should not be copied to the m2 repo.

Is there any known way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

PS: Please note that I'm not asking about -o option to take it offline!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I feel mimicking the ~/.m2 repo would achieve the objective, but the issue is the file system is read-only."?

Comment: that is creating m2 repo in a temp/ folder, and maintaining the Maven repo structure there. But it's not a good solution, so, other developers doesn't like it much!

Comment: As far as I know, a main objective of using maven is to manage dependencies. Does the project have very little amount of dependencies? What is the actual need to use maven?

Comment: As I said, I'm providing the support at the _OS_ level. i.e. no. of dependencies depend on the package users intend to install. So, it varies vastly. The OS should not put a burden on the user's bandwidth if the system already has the required dependencies (but not in a maven repo)

Comment: I'm still not sure I get your requirement. You want to use maven to build your project, but you don't want to download the jars if they are already in the system.So when a user builds your project in their machine, if the jars are already in the system, they will not be downloaded. Is this what you want?

Comment: If you are familiar with Portage Package Manager of Gentoo, I'm trying to add support for Maven projects to it. In that case, it should use existing system packages, instead of downloading the jars from internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach we used is the following.
We've taken a decision to store m2 repo at /usr/share/maven-2/maven_home/m2_repo/. This isn't a temporary folder, and needs admin rights to write. But that isn't a problem since the installing packages also needs admin privileges.

We've symlinked the jars in the repo to point to system-level jars. i.e. we maintained the maven repository structure, but the jars were symlinked them to the system-jars. This means there's no unnecessary duplication and waste of space. We still keep the pom files in repo. The pom files were rewritten by a python script to match our needs.
Further, we refered dependencies with the [*system* scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies). For example,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>666</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>/usr/share/maven-core/lib/maven-core.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

With system scope, it doesn't matter what the groupId:artifactId:version combination. It just picks the jar it find at `<systemPath>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own "mirror" repository (Mirror of actual Maven repository on /tmp) and ask Maven to use that instead of remote repository.

Example :

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: The mirror would still _download_ the artifacts from the internet, doesn't it? The main objective is not depending on the internet, instead use the system jars. The issue with system jars is they are not in a proper package structure (ex. org/apache/???/???.jar) that maven can understand. (or may be it can?)

Comment: That would happen only once. After that you can set the repository to work completely offline.

Comment: I am aware of that. As I said earlier, I need to make it work by using the already downloaded jars (which would have downloaded via maven or by any other method) in a separate location without the maven package structure. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: To provide a custom layout (directory structure), you will need to : `1. Write code java code that implements ArtifactRepositoryLayout interface
2. Make that jar visible to Maven
3. Change configuration of local repository to use your class to resolve path for artifacts

This way you ahve complete control of which path to use for various artifacts.

API : http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/layout/ArtifactRepositoryLayout.html

Example : http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-register-a-custom-maven-repository-layout/


`

Comment: Thanks Shamit. I think we are close. I'm going through your links. One question. Does this mean that we have to change the  POM.xml to specify which directory the build should be deployed? ex: <url>/tmp/repository</url>. 
If so, then, I think it'll still won't be a viable solution. Can we specify the location in ArtifactRepositoryLayout (it'll be hardcoded, but it won't affect the existing poms.). Since, we are going to use a system location like /usr/share/java, the impl should work without any change to poms.

Comment: Yes you can hard code it in the class that implements ArtifactRepositoryLayout .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a local maven repository (with right folders tree and pom files), but use symbol links to jars in your write-only directory. Sure this solution is not easier then Shamit Verma's approach and you must write some code.